# Why am I getting the error 0x4626 when using MC_TorqueControl in simulation mode in TwinCAT?

Tags: twincat

I'm trying to run [`MC_TorqueControl`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_mc2/7617393803.html?id=6677792901421113137) in [simulation mode](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf50x0_tc3_nc_ptp/2834717323.html?id=8250271195349757571), but I get the following error:

`Group function is rejected with error-code 0x4626 or the function is not supported !` and `The axis function 'TorqueControl' has been declined because it's not possible to read the currend generic drive operation mode (error: 0x4626)` (sic).

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulation mode is not supported for TwinCAT versions <3.1.4024.35. To make it work, update both your TwinCAT XAR (runtime) and TwinCAT XAE (engineering) to version >=3.1.4024.35.